# Capturing with vlcj only gives a corrupt video file

Tags: vlc, vlcj

I am using vlcj to capture the screen in my Java program. Therefore I use the following code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
            NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("vlc", "/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                new CaptureTest().start("screen://");
              }
            });
          }

public CaptureTest() {
            factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
            mediaPlayer = (HeadlessMediaPlayer) factory.newMediaPlayer();
          }

          private void start(String mrl) {

            File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Videos");
            dir.mkdirs();

            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss");
            String fileName =  dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/Capture-" + df.format(new Date()) + ".mp4";

            String[] options = {
            ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mp4a}:std{mux=mp4,access=file,dst=" + fileName + "}", ":input-slave=screen://"
            };

            mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release(); 
          }
```

The problem is that the video output file is only 4KB and you can't play it. Can anyone help me? I am on Mac OS 10.6.8 and I use VLC 1.1.12 and vlcj 1.1.5

Comment: Do you mean you want to do screencasting with VLC?

Comment: Have you tested the :sout command option via the VLC command itself rather than Java to see whether it works correctly or not on your PC setup?

Comment: If it doesn't work, please try the VLC command line option given in the following link http://opensource.about.com/od/tutorials/ss/How-To-Capture-A-Screencast-Using-Vlc_6.htm

Comment: If the `dst` parameter in the :sout command option has a filename with spaces in between, you may need to escape the double quotes as follows `"dst=\"" + filename + "\""`

Comment: No I don't want to screencast. I want to record my desktop.
I tested the following on console (Mac OS): /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC screen:// --sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mp4a}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=/User/test/Desktop/test.mp4}"
This worked as expected, it recorded my screen.
The filename has no spaces in it. Maybe you can give me an Java example where it works with mp4 and h264?

Comment: actually the vlc command from http://opensource.about.com/od/tutorials/ss/How-To-Capture-A-Screencast-Using-Vlc_6.htm worked fine. it recorded the screen. but in a very poor quality. The quality with the command i posted above is much better, but it doesnt work (on console it works). what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I modified the :sout command from the link. It works fine on my PC system. It is able to record the desktop screen into a mp4 file. The modified :sout command: `":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,venc=x264{scenecut=100,bframes=0,keyint=10},vb=1024,acodec=none,scale=1.0}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=\""+filename+"\"}}" `

Comment: maybe, you can set none for `acodec` parameter for transcode part first and see what happens.

Comment: For the record, I am using libVLC library and plugins from the stable VLC 1.1.11 for Windows OS via VLCJ 1.2.0

Comment: There is a possible problem in your original code; check my possible answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the interesting part of your code...

```
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
```

Why did you play the media, slept for 5 seconds and stopped immediately after that? Maybe, this is why you get a very small file size during the screen recording. From what I notice, the transcode is not so fast enough, so the file is not increasing in size immediately (maybe due to buffering takes place during transcoding part, I guess...)

The best is to create a button each for the play/record action and for the stop action.

Comment: no, thats definitely not the problem. i found it out myself: i had to add a screen-fps=5.0 option to the options array. after it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm, is it really as simple as that? Because, I don't need to set `screen-fps` at all to succesfully record a desktop screen via VLCJ in my sample code. When I run your code, it is obviously the part I've shown to you doesn't record a file properly since it has been cut short too early (runs for 5 seconds and later stops immediately). That is why the file is just 4KB and doesn't play. For a single frame of 640 x480 x 32 pixels to be recorded, it shall at least produce 9MB size uncompressed. Maybe, you have overlooked something and got lost in finding a solution to your real problem.

Comment: Correction: I forgot to divide by 8...if uncompressed, it shall be at least 1MB  (640 x 480 x 32 /8). 32 bit color/8 = 4 bytes information times the resolution size of a frame... I don't know your desktop size at the time you record it..so, I just assume 640 x 480. But h264 codec involves reduction of information to frame size from one frame state to another if compression takes place.

Comment: Continued... But, I don't think it as a little as 4KB :)

Answer (score 0):

You might check your sout chain.  I also had problem with video file generation. The working sout chain for me is :

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v, vb=4096,scale=1, acodec=mpga, ab=128, channels=2, samplerate=44100}
:duplicate{dst=file{dst="+ fileName+"}, dst=display, select=noaudio}
```