# Screen Capture using Java, making a Java based Screen Recorder

Tags: java, video, screen, record

i want to know is there anyway that using Java one can capture the screen for some particular time, like making a desktop screen cast and then store the result as a video file?

I looked at many resources but could not find any suitable information regarding this. It would be interesting to know if there are any 3rd party libraries available that can do so?

Basically i want to know is there any thing "***JAVA screen Recorder***" that exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java by itself doesn't have this feature. So, to complement such feature, a third-party Java library can be used like VLCJ.

VLCJ is a Java binding to VLC engine (libVLC library and its plugins) used by VLC media player. If you don't know yet, VLC can do screen-cast and screen-capture via its media resource locator (MRL) known as **screen://**

From this MRL, VLC can transcode into another media container and format, stream as a video, or save it to disk.

There is a post related to this in SO: [Capturing with vlcj only gives a corrupt video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067982/capturing-with-vlcj-only-gives-a-corrupt-video-file)

Answer (score 1):

There is no feature of Java (the language) that allows for this. It is hypothetically possible that someone, somewhere, created a Java API for this purpose using JNI, but that does not seem to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler)
,it's a pretty good ffmpeg wrapper.